# Managed Package - Protected Custom Setting for storing creds - Security review

Tags: apex, managed-package, customsetting, security-review

I have created a managed package where I used a **protected Custom Setting** of hierarchy type to store some user credentials.

I am concerned about security review of the app. Is there any chances of getting security review failed when sales force do the review?

I used apex to manage this custom setting data.

Comment: Incidentally, I recently went through a security review in which they themselves actually advised to store credentials in protected custom settings, so you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the past experience, user credentials like password need to be stored either in a protected custom setting or custom metadata for a Managed Package Application.

With protected custom setting subscriber orgs have no way to see them. Only your Managed package apex code can see the data and hence it is safe.

Comment: Thanks @mohit for your answer.